# Java package naming. Underscores: A special case

Tags: java, package, naming, conventions

Today I was naming a package in a project which would contain code related to a concept called an "access structure".

Now, naming this package "com.myemployer.project.component.accessstructures" seems unappealing and difficult to read because of the triple "S".  (The higher level packages are not *actually* named "project" and "component").

I was tempted to use "...component.access_structures"

I couldn't find anything mentioned in the Java conventions on [Oracle's site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) .  And a brief web search brought up nothing.

What is the official convention for names like this?

Comment: Use camel case? `accessStructure`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

> **Package names are written in all lower case** to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.
>
> Companies use their reversed Internet domain name to begin their package names—for example, com.example.mypackage for a package named mypackage created by a programmer at example.com.
>
> Name collisions that occur within a single company need to be handled by convention within that company, perhaps by including the region or the project name after the company name (for example, com.example.region.mypackage).
>
> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, or if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int". In this event, the **suggested convention is to add an underscore**

Although this text doesn't specify your exact case, it does say that for an invalid package name we should use an underscore. One could argue that `accessStructures` is how we would define a method in Java and thus naming a package like that could be confusing.
Overall, it is really up to you.

If you want to keep with this convention, I believe you should name your package:

```
com.myemployer.project.component.access_structures
```

Also you can look up synonyms and find alternatives that would give less confusion. Some I quickly found:

> - accessframework
> - accessfactory
> - accessarch (accessarchitecture)
> - accessconstructs

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, but unfortunately "access structures" is a name that is well entrenched in the domain and we use it when speaking with customers.

For the sake of avoiding confusion, I think we need to stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think  there is any standard for that. People follow different naming conventions as per there convenience and readability. But most of the programmers find camel case naming as the most convenient. You can name it like `accessStructure`

Found one [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) which recommends to use the package name with all small letters

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the
>   names of classes or interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) you can't use `camelCase` for package naming. It's ok to use `snake_case` for package naming in some cases, but it is more appropriate if you can't use your domain properly, because of the hyphen sign in it or it starts with numbers. But it has to be rather an exception from the rule than the rule.

If I were you I would rephrase it. For example: `accessstructures -> accesscore`